# How to handle database interconection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

My users will need to upload files and my application will store them as base64 strings. Firestore isn't optimized to store large files in documents. So I have two choices:

- Upload them to Firebase Storage
- Slice the base64 string in various documents along a collection.

Both of them, will require my application data to keep a reference to storage or collection id.

My dilemma is: if the upload is successful, then I post my data to Firestore. But what if the post fails ? I'll have a uploaded file that isn't referenced by any Firestore document. The same problem if I choose to start by posting the document and then upload the file.

I'm trying to do something stupid ? I'm missing something ? What should I do?

Comment: How large can this files possible be so Firebase storage is not able to handle them?

Comment: The size can vary a lot. At this point, the file type is GLTF (3D scenes).

Comment: Ok, assuming you decompose your base64 strings on the database, your reading/writing quotas would be pretty large and files can be damaged pretty easy. You might want to try firebase storage first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cloud Functions to keep Firestore and Storage in sync.  For example:

1. Write the document to Firestore first, without the path to the file in storage.  remember the unique ID of that document.
2. Then, the client can uploads directly to storage using that ID in the path of the file
3. Cloud Functions trigger fires when the Storage upload is complete, parses the ID of the document out of the file, then updates the matching document in Storage (or creates it if it didn't already exist).

You can also write triggers to keep the document/file pair in sync after one is deleted by deleting the other one.

The key here is that every uploaded file needs to know how to find the paired document, and document needs to also be able to find the paired file.  The unique ID helps with that.

Comment: can I achieve that within a serverless app?

Comment: Cloud Functions **is** serverless.